# What is the difference between ip link "add link" vs "add dev" commands

Tags: linux-networking

I've seen examples of the ip link command where some are shown as

```
ip link add dev xxx type devtype
```

and sometimes its of the form

```
ip link add link xxx type devtype
```

I looked at the documentation and still am confused about the difference between the two. Is there a difference, and if so when would you use one vs the other.

Comment: It's confusing, I hand you that. First, an observation: The top of the [man page](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/ip-link.8.html) puts `[ link DEVICE ]` in brackets. The way I understand it: Some device types, e.g. VXLAN, have a `dev` parameter, so that the `link` parameter becomes redundant and can be left out. Others, e.g. VLAN, don't have a device parameter and need the `link`.

Answer (score 5):

The confusion is caused by abbreviations in the syntax. If you stick to full syntax there will be no confusion.

---

- optional `dev` (and `name`) keywords

  The complete syntax of an usual command (not requiring `link`) is:

  ```
  ip link add name foo type bar ...
  ```

  Now `name` is optional, and in many contexts (not all, see example below) is interchangeable with `dev`. Once the interface is created, it can be set with:

  ```
  ip link set dev foo ...
  ```

  Again here `dev` is optional. `name` or `dev` are needed only when the following parameter would be taken itself as a keyword. So you can create an interface with the name `dev`:

  ```
  ip link add name dev type dummy
  ```

  And rename it into `up` (here `dev` and `name` have not the same role):

  ```
  ip link set dev dev name up
  ```

  But better avoid such strange choices:

  ```
  ip link set dev up name foo
  ```

  When there's no syntax ambiguity some keyword(s) can be omitted. Here `dev` can be omitted because the interface name isn't clashing with a keyword:

  ```
  ip link set foo up
  ```

  So in most cases, you don't see `dev` or `name` in commands handling interfaces. As you can understand, a script manipulating arbitrary interface names should never omit these keywords or suffer unexpected failures.

  Actually, even naming the device is optional. If you don't name a device at creation, it usually adopts a default naming convention that depends on the type, and which is often type+number with number being the next available number. For example:

  ```
  ip link add type bridge
  ```

  will create a bridge interface named `bridge0` unless `bridge0` already exists, in such case it will choose `bridge1` or `bridge2` etc.
- With the `link` keyword

  For interfaces that have a relation with an other interface when created, there's the additional keyword `link` to designate such interface: this happens for VLAN, macvlan ... interfaces. So to create this interface, an other interface must be provided in addition to the chosen name of the new interface:

  ```
  ip link add link foo name bar type vlan id 10
  ```

  Again `name` can be replaced with `dev`:

  ```
  ip link add link foo dev bar2 type vlan id 20
  ```

  And both can be omitted because there's no ambuiguity with the syntax with the current names in use:

  ```
  ip link add link foo mvlan0 type macvlan mode bridge
  ```

  As seen before, if you don't even care to name the created interface, the system will choose a name itself:

  ```
  ip link add link foo type macvlan
  ```

  will create a macvlan interface linked to the parent `foo` interface and name it `macvlan0` or if such name already existed `macvlan1`  etc.

---

In the end it's quite different to use:

```
  ip link add link foo type macvlan
```

where system gets to choose the name of an interface linked with `foo`

rather than:

```
  ip link add dev foo type bridge
```

where you create an interface named `foo`. The type matters and is not interchangeable here, but for example:

```
  ip link add link foo type bridge
```

will also work, but ignore the unneeded parameters `link foo` and will create a bridge interface named for example `bridge1`.

Any confusion that can happen is caused by abbreviations. If you keep the full syntax, there won't be any confusion possible. That's also what should be done with automated scripts.

Comment: When using `ip link add`, what's the difference between the `dev DEVICE` and `NAME`? That is' what does the `DEVICE` parameter do differently from the `NAME` parameter?

Comment: @CMCDragonkai As written in the first bullet, in contexts where there is no confusion possible `dev` and `name` are interchangeable (I wrote `name` the keyword, I don't know what you mean with uppercase `NAME`). So sometimes `dev DEVICE` and `name DEVICE` are equivalent. Again, I don't know what you mean with uppercase `NAME`

Answer (score 2):

when i run the command
`ip link add link foo type bridge`
on debian10, it will not ignore the unneeded parameters but report a error:

```
root@debian10:~#  ip link add link foo type bridge
Cannot find device "foo"
```

so the device `foo` must exists on the system, it will then ignore the unneeded parameters(here that is `link foo`) without any error report